# What are the alternatives for an ORDER BY clause in a View?

Tags: sql-server, view, order-by

This question just had to be in this site :)

ORDER BY is forbidden to use in a view, as I understood because of the possibility for multiple order by's when using this view.

I know that there are ways of bypassing this limitation, for example `TOP 99.999999 PERCENT`, but I would like to know what is the best practice, not how to hack it.

So, if I want to create views in my database for personal use, meaning I want to connect to the database and just see the data fixed and sorted, how should I do it if I can't order a view?

Currently in my SQL Server DB I have views with the `TOP` hack, and I'm using them a lot, but it feels wrong.

Comment: why not TOP 100%?

Comment: @garik - because it still doesn't *guarantee* the ordering if I understand gbn's link correctly. It is just a more concise wrong answer

Comment: @Jack Douglas it was not an answer, it was a comment about top 99.999...

Comment: @garik - in SQL Server 2008 the TOP 100 PERCENT is ignored, and only using 99 is working. I think it was fixed but my version isn't updated.

Comment: This is not a technical limitation.  This is by design.  That's why any workaround feels like a hack. Impose your ordering in the queries against the views. An order applies to a result-set (e.ge query output), not a collection of data (e.g. a view or table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "ordered" view because a view is supposed to be a set of rows. Use a stored procedure if you want a fixed ordering.

Comment: This is the answer that explains _why_ you cannot impose an ordering inside a view definition. A set, by definition, does not have an order. When you combine `TOP` with `ORDER BY`, however, you are now defining a new set since the ordering affects which rows are "top"; this is why `TOP` enables you to use `ORDER BY` in a view definition.

Answer (score 9):

**Only** the outermost ORDER BY will guarantee order

- Any intermediate or internal ORDER BY is ignored.
  This includes ORDER BY in a view
- There is no implied order in any table
- There is no implied order from any index (clustered or not) on that table

Links

- ["Sorting Rows with ORDER BY"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188723.aspx) (MSDN)

> ORDER BY guarantees a sorted result only for the outermost SELECT statement of a query. For example, consider the following view definition: (and example follow that matches this question)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but it's not the answer I was looking for :) I'm trying to see what kind of alternatives are there for the very convenient ORDER BY inside a view.

Answer (score 3):

Add an ORDER BY to the output of the view i.e.

```
  SELECT whatever FROM MYVIEW ORDER BY whatever
```

Comment: There is no implied order by clustered index. -1.

Comment: @SqlACID - good edit, +1 instead of -1 :)

Comment: This means you need to rewrite the order by clause every time you query the view, which is what we're trying to avoid when we use the order by inside the view.

Comment: as dportas said, a stored proc wrapper around the query would work, but probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: I actually tried stored procedure but it wasn't easy and quick enough to query or manipulate. Meh.